# Markdown plugin for jEdit?

Tags: plugins, markdown, jedit

I want to use markdown syntax for taking notes in class, so I looked around and I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/87273/desktop-app-for-wiki-like-markdown-markups) as a partial answer.  I'm now wondering if there is a good Markdown plugin (specifically, as opposed to a Markdown-like syntax) for jEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like Ali Rantakari's [Markdown and POD Syntax Highlighting Modes for jEdit](http://hasseg.org/blog/?p=302)?