# Writing corporate documentation in Markdown and pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

## Background

I have had a few friends that turned me on to `markdown` and `pandoc` for writing documentation. At my current job, we use *Microsoft Word* for writing unstructured, one-off howto documents for our end users. I would like to start writing them in markdown for the following reasons.

1. separation of content from structure.
2. the ability to use change control systems to track updates
3. Build a standard template that includes a logo, boilerplate company text, a layout that is common to all subsequent documentation.

I would like to build a few templates that will allow all documents to contain the same flow of information to our users. The goal is add a professorial look to our IT department user documentation.

I imagine that a company hosted wiki may suffice, but the decision makers won't allow that at this given time.

## Question

What I am looking for is help in adding elements like a logo, and standard text that can be added to an HTML or PDF template. Also, I would like to define macros like encapsulating a word in `!` bangs would highlight that word according to a set of rules, like keys on a keyboard or buttons of a software GUI. In contrast, encapsulating a word in `&` ampersands would change the style to signify the name of a GUI Menu element.

Comment: That's probably a good goal, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: This question is *way* to broad. Please go read a [tutorial](https://www.google.se/search?q=markdown+tutorial+%2Bpandoc) and return when you have specific questions.

Comment: If you're still looking, this might help: http://superuser.com/questions/87273/desktop-app-for-wiki-like-markdown-markups/87277#87277